# finding the first occurrence of a negative number in a given list using while loop in a function

Tags: python

I have an assignment in which I have to return the first occurrence of a negative number from a given list. and I am expected to use this function  --> `def first_neg(a):`

This is the setup:

```
def first_neg(a):
    # my code here

# Testcases
print(first_neg([2, 3, -1, 4, -2])) # expecting 2
print(first_neg([2, 3, 1, 4, 2]))   # expecting None
print(first_neg([]))                # expecting None
```

I tried doing this but I can sense many mistakes in it

```
def first_neg(a):
i = 0

while i < len(first_neg):
  if first_neg[i] < 0:
    return a[i]
  else:
    i = i+1
```

when I do this and apply the testcases, it gives me an error

```
TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()
```

Comment: Which part of the task is confusing?

Comment: I suggest removing the bolded first sentence, it's a bit unnecessary.

Comment: `first_neg` is just the name of your function, change every reference to `first_neg` after the first line to `a` (the list you're passing in as a parameter) - and return `a[i]` not `[i]`

Comment: `negative_values = [i for i,j in enumerate(your_list) if j < 0]
    first_negative = negative_values[0]`

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and english is not my first language so I am having trouble knowing how to word my question where I can get feedback. I am sorry in advance

Comment: I would suggest: `next((i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x < 0), None)`

Comment: question has been improved, voted to reopen

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
def first_neg(a):
  i = 0
  while i < len(a):
    if a[i] < 0:
      return i
    else:
      i = i + 1
```